# Understanding vector initialization in C++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

If I've got a constructor with an initialization list as such:

```
std::vector<int> _list;  

Program::Program() : _list(0)
{
}
```

Does this initialize all values to 0 even when the vector resizes itself?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.  The vector you posted has no entries -- vector's just don't resize by themselves.  You have to call one of the vector's functions to do that, such as `push_back`, `insert`, `emplace_back`, `resize`. When you call those functions, you're controlling what gets placed in the vector.

Comment: SInce leading underscore is a convention used for the implementation's custom identifiers in the global namespace, it's commonly avoided for one's own identifiers. A common convention for member variables is the one used in the Boost library, with a trailing underscore.

Comment: Please clarify the question.

Comment: if you call [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) to do the resizing, then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the argument of the vector constructor that you're calling. `_list(0)` will initialise `_list` to length zero, using the default value for type int, which also happens to be zero, but which is irrelevant if the vector doesn't contain any elements. It doesn't explicitly set element *values* to zero. Perhaps you meant to have the constructor repeats a single value a specified number of times? If so, you need to pass the desired length as the first argument, and the value to repeat for its second argument. This construction does not affect an subsequent resizing to expand the vector, which will populate the new vector elements with the default value (or a different value if you specify one as an additional argument to `vector::resize`).

Here's an example to illustrate, based on your code, which first initialises the vector with the value `10` repeating for length 5, and then resizes the vector to length 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Program
{
public:
    Program() : _list(0) { }
    Program(unsigned long size, int value) : _list(size, value) { }

    void ResizeList(unsigned long size)
    {
        _list.resize(size);
    }

    void PrintList() const
    {
        std::cout << "_list = ";
        for (const auto& val : _list)
        {
            std::cout << val << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> _list;
};

int main()
{
    Program p(5, 10);
    p.PrintList();

    p.ResizeList(10);
    p.PrintList();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
_list = 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
_list = 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

Comment: So you don't really need to initialize it at all if you're just using it as a list, right? Just push_back items and you're good?

Comment: If you want it to start empty, then that's exactly right. Empty is the default behaviour if you don't specify any other initialisation (meaning you omit it from the member initializer list in the constructor of the class that owns it), and then you can add the values you want using `push_back`.

Comment: And if I use resize on a vector, the added elements will be 0?

Comment: Yes, a vector of int will have zeroes added when you expand it via `resize`, unless you explicitly specify a different default value to use by passing it as a second parameter to `resize`.

Comment: Got it. I guess that's what you had to do explicitly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the documentation for the `std::vector` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), you'll see that for constructor `(3)`, the one you're using, you'll see that you're constructing `0` elements of type `int` in-place in `_list`. This means that you're essentially doing nothing.

When the vector is resized, the elements that space is allocated for will be uninitialized, unless you use the `resize` function, in which case the elements will be initialized to their default value, or a value of your choice.

For example, if your vector were empty and you did `_list.resize(10);`, `_list` would now contain 10 elements of the default-constructed type of `int`, which should just be `0`. If you instead did something like `_list.resize(10, 5);`, `_list` would now contain 10 `5`s.

I hope this helped clear things up for you. If you have any follow up questions, feel free to ask.